# Vanilla Javascript Arrays Objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

Here is my code:

```
const notes = [{}, {
  title: 'My next trip',
  body: 'I would like to go to Spain'
}, {
  title: 'Habits to work on',
  body: 'Excercise.  Eating a bit better'
}, {
  title: 'Office modification',
  body: 'Get a new seat'
}]

const findNote = function (notes, noteTitle) {
  return notes.find(function(note, index) {
    return note.title === noteTitle
  })
}

const filteredNotes = notes.filter(function (note, index) {
  const isTitleMatch = note.title.toLocaleLowerCase().includes('o')
  const isBodyMatch = note.body.toLocaleLowerCase().includes('ne')
  return isTitleMatch || isBodyMatch
})
console.log(filteredNotes)
```

When I run it in the console, I get an error :
TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined

When I can the .toLowerCase() out, I get the error:
const isTitleMatch = note.title.includes('ne')
                                  ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined

What am I doing wrong, I am relatively new to Javascript only at it for about 2 weeks now.

Comment: That's because the first object in the array is empty!

Comment: @Li357 Exactly! The first element is {}, so it doesn't have the title property or the body. Hence it is undefined.

Comment: Silly mistake, thank you guys so much!